# Gradle fails to sync after upgrading to Cordova Android 8.0

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, android-min-sdk

I just upgraded from cordova 7.1.4 to cordova 8.0.0. The build is successful on WebStorm, but the apk delivered can not be installed and when I open it in Android Studio gradle fails to sync with the following errors: “

```
The minSdk version should not be declared in the android manifest file. You can move the version from the manifest to the defaultConfig in the build.gradle file.

    Open Manifest File

Move minSdkVersion to build file and sync project
```

”.

I can fix these errors on Android Studio but I need that WebStorm to deliver a valid apk.
I added `<preference name=”android-minSdkVersion” value=”19" />` to config.xml but it is not read from there.
On `Cordova 8.0.0` changes is mentioned “ Use custom Gradle properties to read `minSdkVersion` value from `config.xml`"but I don’t understand what this means….I read on an article that an `after_prepare` hook script whould be the best solution.

Any idea how this script should look like?
Any idea is welcome.

PS: I know the `Cordova 9.0.0` fixed this problem, it reads `minSdkVersion` from config.xml file, but I need to fix this on `Cordova 8.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config)

```
   <!-- These preferences are actually available in Cordova by default although not currently documented -->
<custom-preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="10" />
<custom-preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="22" />
<custom-preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="21" />

<!-- Or you can use a custom-config-file element for them -->
<custom-config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
    <uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="22" android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
</custom-config-file>
```

If this fails, then you have this option

> build-extras.gradle with the following content:
>
> allprojects { project.ext { defaultMinSdkVersion=21 } }
>
> copy this file in the platforms/android folder with a before_build
>   hook and it does the job.

Or this

> changing lines in file:
>   platforms/android/gradle.properties
>
> org.gradle.daemon=true org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m
>   android.useDeprecatedNdk=true cdvMinSdkVersion=21
>
> to
>
> org.gradle.daemon=true org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m
>   android.useDeprecatedNdk=true cdvMinSdkVersion=19

[reference](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/686)

Comment: I tried all these solutions but it is not working. I don't understand why.